# Fullscreen Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, html5, firefox, видео

Объясните, пожалуйста почему вход в полноэкранный режим работает, выход нет:

```
if (e.which == 70)
{
        if(vid.requestFullScreen)
        {
            vid.requestFullScreen();
        }
...
else if (vid.mozRequestFullScreen)               // Firefox 
        {          
            vid.mozRequestFullScreen();                             
        }
...
if (vid.exitFullScreen && e.which == 70)    
{
    vid.exitFullscreen();
} 
else if (vid.cancelFullScreen && e.which == 70)              // Firefox
{
  vid.cancelFullScreen();
} 
else if (vid.mozCancelFullScreen && e.which == 70) 
{
  vid.mozCancelFullScreen();
} 
else if (vid.webkitCancelFullScreen && e.which == 70) 
{
  vid.webkitCancelFullScreen();
}
```

Ещё хотелось бы знать, как отображать свой персонализированный контрол бар в полноэкранном режиме, в Chrome и Opera все работает, а вот Mozilla и IE 11 не хотят. В хроме решил добавлением макс.значения z-index: 2147483648; а тут не знаю как, помогите.

Answer (score 1):

Вот это примерный код который работает для `firefox`.

```
if (exports.document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
    // https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=867967
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    // **Note:** Following workaround doesn't work for Android FF
    var $fullScreenElement = $(document.mozFullScreenElement);
    var $fullScreenElementPrev = $fullScreenElement.prev();
    $fullScreenElement.detach().insertAfter($fullScreenElementPrev);
} else if (exports.document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
    exports.document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
}
```

Можете кастомизировать под ваши нужды.

Answer (score 1):

```
function requestFullScreen() {
    var isInFullScreen = (document.fullscreenElement && document.fullscreenElement !== null) ||
        (document.webkitFullscreenElement && document.webkitFullscreenElement !== null) ||
        (document.mozFullScreenElement && document.mozFullScreenElement !== null) ||
        (document.msFullscreenElement && document.msFullscreenElement !== null);

    var docElm = document.documentElement;
    if (!isInFullScreen) {
        if (docElm.requestFullscreen)
            docElm.requestFullscreen();
        else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen)
            docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
        else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen)
            docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        else if (docElm.msRequestFullscreen)
            docElm.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
    else {
        if (document.exitFullscreen)
            document.exitFullscreen();
        else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen)
            document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen)
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        else if (document.msExitFullscreen)
            document.msExitFullscreen();
    }

}
```

Рабочий кроссбраузерный пример

Comment: var docElm = document.documentElement; Эту строку не понимаю